# Room Database cannot add more than 1 item to the data bas

Tags: java, android, database, android-room

In this Android Studio Example I completed Room Database Architecture and try to insert some persons to my database and I added person1 and person2 in my PersonRoomDatabase class but when I start my project I saw only person1 in the Database Inspector Screen. I tried to add the person3 in my Main Activity that is not worked too. Even though I change person1's name it is still remains "saul". Shortly I can not add or insert any Person object to my Database ecxept person1. If you can help me I would be grateful <3

1.)RoomDatabase class:

```
    @Database(entities = {Person.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
    public abstract class PersonRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    
       public abstract PersonDAO personRoomDAO();

    private static volatile PersonRoomDatabase INSTANCE;
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS=4;
    static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor=enter code here
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);

    //We defined singleton for PersonRoomDatabase so there will be just one Database
    static final PersonRoomDatabase getDatabase(final Context context){
        if (INSTANCE==null){
            synchronized (PersonRoomDatabase.class){
                if (INSTANCE==null){
                    INSTANCE= Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                    PersonRoomDatabase.class,"person_database")
                            .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);

            databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
              
                PersonDAO dao = INSTANCE.personRoomDAO();
                dao.deleteAll();

                Person person1=new Person("saul","goodman");
                dao.insert(person1);

                Person person2=new Person("walter","white");
                dao.insert(person2);


            });
        }
    };
}
```

2.)DAO Class:

```
@Dao

public interface PersonDAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)

void insert(Person person);

@Query("DELETE FROM person_table")

void deleteAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM person_table ORDER BY name ASC")

LiveData<List<Person>> selectAllPerson();

}
```

3.)View Model Class:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private PersonRepository personViewModelRepository;

private final LiveData<List<Person>> allPersonViewModel;

public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    personViewModelRepository=new PersonRepository(application);
    allPersonViewModel=personViewModelRepository.getAllPersonsRepository();
}

public LiveData<List<Person>> getAllPersonViewModel(){return allPersonViewModel;}

public void insert(Person person){ personViewModelRepository.insert(person);}

public void deleteAll(){personViewModelRepository.deleteAll();}
}
```

4.)Repository Class:

```
public class PersonRepository {
private PersonDAO personRepositoryDAO;
private LiveData<List<Person>> allPersons;



PersonRepository (Application application){
    PersonRoomDatabase db=PersonRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);

    personRepositoryDAO=db.personRoomDAO();

    allPersons=personRepositoryDAO.selectAllPerson();
}


LiveData<List<Person>> getAllPersonsRepository() {
    return allPersons;
}

exception. Room ensures

void insert(Person person){
    PersonRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() ->
            personRepositoryDAO.insert(person));
}
void deleteAll(){
    PersonRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() ->
            personRepositoryDAO.deleteAll());
}

}
```

5.)My Person Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "person_table")
public class Person {

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "id")
private int id;

@ColumnInfo(name = "name")
private String name;

@ColumnInfo(name = "lastName")
private String lastName;

public Person(){

}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Person(String name, String lastName) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

}
```

6.)Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Person person;
private PersonViewModel personViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    personViewModel= new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(MainActivity.this
            .getApplication())
            .create(PersonViewModel.class);


    
    Person person3=new Person("jesse","pinkman");
    personViewModel.insert(person3);


    personViewModel.getAllPersonViewModel().observe(this,person ->
            Log.d("Observe", "onCreate: "+person.get(0).getName())


    );





}

}
```

Comment: It appears you are trying to add `person2` before the object is even created.

Comment: As @BlackHatSamu points out, you create person1 but insert perser2. same thing in the next two lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, adding `@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)` to the `id` field allows you to insert properly without specifying the `id` manually.

The reason only one person was added to the table before (despite calling `insert` more than once)  is that when you use the `public Person(String name, String lastName)` constructor, Java automatically initializes `id` to the default `int` value of 0. Thus, all of the `Person` objects you created had a primary key of 0. The first time you inserted one of these instances, there was no row in the database with primary key 0 and the insert succeeded. On subsequent calls, a `Person` with primary key 0 already existed, so the new `Person` was not inserted. This is the default behavior for Room insert methods, but you can change it. For example, if you wanted the new entry to replace the old one, you could add the annotation `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` to the insert method. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy) for a list of possible behaviors.

Comment: Ok man now I understand the mechanism behind it thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Guys I finally figured out what is the problem:
When I am trying to insert a person object I only wrote name and lastname but the think that I forgot is id.So object is couldnt created and inserted to the our database.
Solution is I annoted id field @Primary(aoutoGenerate=true) so it will autogenerate the id even I didnt insert the id.

But the think that I didnt understand is even though I didnt insert the id at the beginning (before the I coded aoutoGenerate=true) it took just one person to the table anybody can explain?